# IDLE throws an error message - *name 'abc' is not defined *

Tags: python

I have written a small script using function . When i run the script NameError ( name 'abc' is not defined ) . Please help me out where i am going wrong

```
abc()

def abc():
    print("printed")
```

Output :

```
[error] script [ Untitled ] stopped with error in line 1
[error] NameError ( name 'abc' is not defined )
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly and what you're trying to is just run your `abc()` function, you have to switch places between your function definition and the actual function call. So it will be like that:

```
def abc():
    print("printed")

abc()
```

**BTW**, it has nothing to do with Sikuli. This is how Python works.